# Adding unique axes label names in ggplot with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

It seems like many users are trying to do what I am also trying here.

**I am trying to do these things:**

1. x-axis labels to be fixed (range 0 to 1200), the x-axis to be repeated on each plot, and for the x-axis label name to be repeated and customizable for each plot
2. y-axis labels to be free (but to be able to edit the range in the second plot to be `breaks=c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12)`), the y-axis to be repeated on each plot, and for the y-axis labels to be repeated and customizable for each plot

Using the below code ([adapted](http://lacey.se/2016/09/21/a-half-solution-for-multiple-y-axes-with-ggplot/) [from](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/3.2.0/topics/facet_wrap) [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677561/r-ggplot-facet-wrap-with-different-y-axis-labels-one-values-one-percentages) [OPs and documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573155/showing-different-axis-labels-using-ggplot2-with-facet-wrap)):

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=dist, fill=sex)) +
   geom_histogram(data = cbind(move, panel = "A"), color="black", binwidth=10) +
   geom_vline(data = cbind(move, panel = "A"), aes(xintercept=mean(dist)), 
    color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
   geom_histogram(data = cbind(settle_data, panel = "B"), color="black", binwidth=10) +
   geom_vline(data = cbind(settle_data, panel = "B"), aes(xintercept=mean(dist)), 
    color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
   geom_histogram(data = cbind(recruit_data, panel = "C"), color="black", binwidth=10) +
   geom_vline(data = cbind(recruit_data, panel = "C"), aes(xintercept=mean(dist)), 
    color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1200))+ #limits axes range without deleting points
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray97", "gray47"),
            name = "Sex",   
            breaks=c("F","M"),
            labels=c("Female","Male")) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.8,0.8), #move legend into plot
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text=element_text(size = 20), #changes size of axes #s
        axis.title=element_text(size=20), #changes size of axes labels
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 2.12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 15)) +
    facet_wrap(~ panel, ncol = 1, scales='free_y', labeller=as_labeller(c(A = "Number of fixes", B = "Number of individuals", C = "Number of individuals") ), strip.position="left") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1250,by = 200)) +     
    theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 19))+
    labs(x = "Distance travelled from natal nest (m)")
```

Resulting plot (I was able to "hack" the y-axis issues I was having by moving the panel names to the left outside of the plots and act like they were axis labels):

[image]

The plot I want (edits circled in red):
[image]

I cannot post the data I used for the plots, but I've created a sample dataset below:

```
move<- data.frame(
    dist = c(0,100,200,300,400,400,500,600,700,800,1000,1200,0,100,200,300,400,400,500,600,700,800,1000,1200,0,100,200,300,400,400,500,600,700,800,1000,1200,0,100,200,300,400,400,500,600,700,800,1000,1200),
    sex = c ("F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F","F","F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F","F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F","F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F"))
settle_data<-data.frame(
    dist = c(0,10,20,30,400,40,50,60,700,80,1000,1200,0,10,20,30,400,40,50,60,700,80,1000,1200, 0,10,20,30,400,40,50,60,700,80,1000,1200,0,100,200,300,400,400,500,600,700,800,1000,1200,0,10,20,30,400,40,50,60,700,80,1000,1200,0,10,20,30,400,40,50,60,700,80,1000,1200,0,10,20,30,400,40,50,60,700,80,1000,1200,0,100,200,300,400,400,500,600,700,800,1000,1200),
    sex = c ("F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F","F","F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F","F", "M","F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F","F", "M", "F", "F","F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M","M", "M", "F", "F","F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M","F", "F","F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F","F", "M","F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F"))
recruit_data<- data.frame(
    dist = c(0,10,20,30,400,40,50,60,700,80,1000,1200,0,10,20,30,4,40,50,60,700,80,10,120,0,10,20,30,40,40,50,60,70,80,100,120,0,100,200,300,400,400,500,600,700,800,1000,1200),
    sex = c ("F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F","F","F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F","F", "M","F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F","F", "M", "F", "F","F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F"))
```

Comment: If you're plotting three different data frames with three different axes, consider making three separate plots and using `grid.arrange` or `arrangeGrob`

Comment: Since you want separate axis labels and fine-tuned control over the axes, I second the idea that making separate plots might be the way to go.  See packages cowplot, patchwork, and egg for some nice tools for combining separate plots.

Comment: For the y axis breaks issue you may be able to use `scales::pretty_breaks()` as discussed [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/separate-axis-breaks-for-facets/10352/2).  For the x axis, you could allow free x scales but then set the limits and breaks with `scale_x_continuous. This would give you an axis for each plot but have the limits/breaks be the same (but only one overall axis label).

Comment: Using `lemon::facet_rep_wrap(~panel, ncol=1, strip.position='b', repeat.tick.labels='bottom')` will place the panel names on the bottom of each facet and repeat the x-axis labels.

Comment: As @teunbrand points out, when I used `grid.arrange` the y-axes do not line up given the top plot has 4 digit numbers which pushes that plot in further than the two lower plots (with only 1 digit numbers on the y-axes). Also, I am looking for a general solution that works with `facet_wrap` given the OP is only an example of the kind of problem I keep encountering with `facet_wrap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with most of the comments that it would be easier to make seperate plots. A painpoint of such an approach is often that the alignment of the axes is off. To counteract this, I'll point towards the [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) package, that takes out most of this pain.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

# Get some basic plots
dat_list <- list(move, recruit_data, settle_data)

plots <- lapply(dat_list, function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(dist, fill = sex)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 10) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1200)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
})

# Make adjustments to each plot as needed
plots[[1]] <- plots[[1]] + labs(x = "Distance settled (m)", y = "Number of fixes") + 
  theme(legend.position = c(1,1), legend.justification = c(1,1))

plots[[2]] <- plots[[2]] + labs(x = "Distance recruited (m)", y = "Number of individuals") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 12, by = 3), limits = c(0, 12))

plots[[3]] <- plots[[3]] + labs(x = "Distance from natal nest (m)", y = "Number of individuals")

# Patchwork all the plots together
plots[[1]] + plots[[2]] + plots[[3]] + plot_layout(nrow = 3)
```

[image]

And finetune to taste.

Answer (score 5):

For those who want or need to use `facet_wrap`, here is the solution that worked for me (pulling up suggestions from the comments).

**The below edits gave the following plot:**

[image]

**The important notes on the edits:**

`coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1200))` sets limit for x axis to be the same for all plots

`scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(5))` made the y-axes not have decimals

`labs(x = "")` adds an x-axis to the very bottom

To add a label to each other plot, `geom_text()` allowed for this simply by changing which plot (`panel=c("B")` and `panel=c("C")`) the annotation appeared in.

**Within `facet_wrap()`:**

`scales='free'` makes it so that the axes are repeated for every plot

`labeller=as_labeller(c([text]))` can be used to give each plot its own unique y-axis name

`strip.position='left'` moves the panels to the left side (where the y-axis would be)

**Within `theme()`:**

`strip.placement = "outside"` moves the panel labels to the outside of the plot, allowing them to act as y-axes label names

**The code used:**

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=dist, fill=sex)) +
   geom_histogram(data = cbind(move, panel = "A"), color="black", binwidth=10) +
   geom_vline(data = cbind(move, panel = "A"), aes(xintercept=mean(dist)), 
    color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
   geom_histogram(data = cbind(settle_data, panel = "B"), color="black", binwidth=10) +
   geom_vline(data = cbind(settle_data, panel = "B"), aes(xintercept=mean(dist)), 
    color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
   geom_histogram(data = cbind(recruit_data, panel = "C"), color="black", binwidth=10) +
   geom_vline(data = cbind(recruit_data, panel = "C"), aes(xintercept=mean(dist)), 
    color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1)+
    coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1200))+ 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray97", "gray47"),
            name = "Sex",   
            breaks=c("F","M"),
            labels=c("Female","Male")) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.95,0.93), #move legend into plot
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text=element_text(size = 20), #changes size of axes #s
        axis.title=element_text(size=20), #changes size of axes labels
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 2.12),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 20)) +
    facet_wrap(~ panel, ncol = 1, scales='free', labeller=as_labeller(c(A = "Number of fixes", B = "Number of individuals", C = "Number of individuals") ), strip.position="left") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1250,by = 200)) +  
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(5))+  
    theme(
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 19))+
    labs(x = "Distance recruited from natal nest (m)")+
 geom_text(data=data.frame(x=600, y=12, 
        label="Distance travelled from natal nest (m)", panel=c("B")), 
               aes(x,y,label=label), inherit.aes=FALSE, size = 7) +
 geom_text(data=data.frame(x=600, y=6, 
        label="Distance settled from natal nest (m)", panel=c("C")), 
               aes(x,y,label=label), inherit.aes=FALSE, size = 7)
```